# Why onclick event doesn't work in neither JavaScript nor Thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying hit the button to add a new dynamic row in the table. My project construction is spring boot, I put the HTML in the templates. I try to use "onclick" function to jump to javascript, however, it doesn't work either "th:onclick" or "onclick".

```
<td><button onclick="add(this)">Add</button></td>
<td><button th:onclick="'javascript:add(this)'">Add</button></td>
```

Either of these two methods is noticing me an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined"

The following code is my js, I think I defined the function add(). Why doesn't it work?

```
function add(object) {
var tr = object.parentNode.parentNode;
var row = tr.rowIndex;
var tab = document.getElementById("tableA");
tab.style.cssText="width:80%; height: 100%; table-layout:fixed";
var objRow1 = tab.insertRow(row++);

var objCell;
var objCell1;
var objCell2;
var objCell3;
var objCell4;
var objCell5;
var objCell6;
var objCell7;
objCell = objRow1.insertCell(0);
objCell.innerHTML='<input type="text" id="SystemName" name="SystemName" value=""/>';
objCell.style.cssText="width:auto; height:auto; word-wrap: break-word;white-space: nowrap;"
objCell1 = objRow1.insertCell(1);
objCell1.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="IP" id="IP" value=""/>';
objCell1.style.cssText="width:auto; height:auto; word-wrap: break-word;white-space: nowrap;"
objCell2 = objRow1.insertCell(2);
objCell2.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="SystemLevel" id="SystemLevel" value=""/>';
objCell2.style.cssText="width:auto; height:auto; word-wrap: break-word;white-space: nowrap;"
objCell3 = objRow1.insertCell(3);
objCell3.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="Ownera" id="Ownera" value=""/>';
objCell3.style.cssText="width:auto; height:auto; word-wrap: break-word;white-space: nowrap;"
objCell4 = objRow1.insertCell(4);
objCell4.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="Ownerb" id="Ownerb" value=""/>';
objCell4.style.cssText="width:auto; height:auto; word-wrap: break-word;white-space: nowrap;"
objCell5 = objRow1.insertCell(5);
objCell5.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="SystemDesc" id="SystemDesc" value=""/>';
objCell5.style.cssText="width:auto; height:auto; word-wrap: break-word;white-space: nowrap;"
objCell6 = objRow1.insertCell(6);
objCell6.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="SystemDate" id="SystemDate" value=""/>';
objCell6.style.cssText="width:auto; height:auto; word-wrap: break-word;white-space: nowrap;"
objCell7 = objRow1.insertCell(7);
objCell7.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="Recorder" id="Recorder" value=""/>';
objCell7.style.cssText="width:auto; height:auto; word-wrap: break-word;white-space: nowrap;"
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the JavaScript is loaded and that the `add` function is bound to `window`? If you defined the `add` function within a different scope, your browser won't know about it. Try to add something like `window.add = add;` in your JavaScript file.

Comment: Where did you define the `add` function? Before or after the `onclick`? You usually get "Uncaught ReferenceError" when you called a function before it was actually defined.

Comment: What does the js-console says?

Comment: @g00glen00b Yes, the JavaScript is loaded. Sorry, I just start with js, I don't understand about add function within a different scope? I put js document into the resources, and define the script classpath.

Comment: @vronjec How to define add function before or after the onclick?

Comment: @MichaelHu If you wrap your `add()` function in another function, then it isn't bound to the `window` scope but to a different one. If you open your console and enter `add()` does it call your function or not? Anyhow, the function in its current state should be called, so I'm voting to close since the problem isn't within the code we can see.

Comment: @g00glen00b I think it isn't coded problem since the add () function could be called in my another project, besides this one with spring boot. Or I code wrong with thymeleaf to impact the js? In this spring boot project, I can't call any js function. I don't know why?

Comment: @MichaelHu And I don't think the problem is with Spring boot since Spring boot just renders the Thymeleaf template as HTML and serves the JavaScript files. If  the JavaScript file is loaded into the browser as you said, and the Thymeleaf template is exactly the one mentioned in the question, it **will** work. I even confirmed that by creating a new Spring boot project with Thymeleaf and a button with a JavaScript `onclick` handler. If you don't provide us with additional details, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is problem with your html code that prevent running your function. Have you tried that if atleast your function is running or not?

Comment: I can make sure that the js function can run. I tried it in another project. What's the problem with my HTML code that prevents running the js function?

Comment: There could be missing closing tag or something like that.Have you tried to F12 to see if there is any error in console.

Comment: Yes, there are no other closing tags or something like, the only error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined".

Comment: It is working fine here. Are you importing script? And check table Id too.

Comment: Both of them are right, I double check it. I use both thymeleaf and regular methods to import the script.